# Since when this exsite in VanillaJS?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i used to select ID from the DOM by using
`const elem = document.getElementById('ID');`
in order to manipulate an element

recently by accident encounter this : (see snippet below)
i can select a DOM element by its ID just by write the id as variable and i can manipulated how its even possible ?

this is a working fiddle [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/zyv68h5u/1/)

```
myInput.value = 'hello world'
<input type="text" id="myInput">
```

Comment: Since the 1990s

Comment: ^^ but relying on it is a Bad Idea™. Stick with `getElementById`. There are too many conflicting names in the global namespace.